# How to deal with combination of text and numeric features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Looking at Kaggel's [Job Salary Prediction](http://www.kaggle.com/c/job-salary-prediction), I see numeric features (like Category) and textual ones (like FullDescription).

How do I go about training on such data? I thought about vectorizing the text using [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer), however it creates sparse matrix which many learning algorithms (such as [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor)) refuse to work with. Also, once I have the feature vector for the text, how do I combine it with other features?

Any pointers on how to work with such data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first learn a linear model on the tf-idf features of each text field independently and add the linear models predictions as a additional feature to the other features and train an `ExtraTreesRegressor` or `GradientBoostedTreeRegressor` on the combined features.

Comment: Let us know if the combined model is any better than just a linear model on the text features or a random forest on the non-text features only.

Comment: Linear model regressors such as ElasticNet and SGDRegressor should work out of the box and so it the case for non linear SVR or NuSVR regressors. Tree based regressors do not support sparse input yet.

Comment: @ogrisel: How much of a gain are you expecting by using this dual-model approach? Why not just use your hashingvectorizer combined with SGD (or whatever other linear model that allows partial fitting)?

Comment: SGD is a linear model which is often good enough for high dimensional data such as text bag of words features alone. However for the rest of the features, they might have predictive non linear interactions that could potentially be exploited by kernel SVM, GBRT or Extra Trees regressor models.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion , do you mean to train text only feature first and then stack the corresponding prediction both to train and test data and run extratreeregressor ? I think it's the only possible way , if I stack the linear regresor output back to test then train would have 1 less column dim.